# Some errors with getting @:genericbuild working (haxe nightly)

Tags: macros, haxe

Now [Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481810/some-errors-with-genericbuilding-enums)

This post is a follow up on a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452808/how-to-make-an-parametrized-enum-build-macro)

I have taken example code with @:genericbuild which runs ok and modified it, but then it doesn't run.

While I am not new to haxe I am totally new when it comes to macro's. I am used to thoroughly look in documentation and even code if documentation is hard to find. But with haxe macro's that isn't so easy, that's why I hope to find some answers here. With those answers I hope to gain knowledge so I can help improving haxe documentation, so others new to macro's have an easier time.

I have studied documentation available and code.

There are 3 files. The file with driver code (Main.hx), a parameterised enum being generated by a macro(Either.hx) making use of @:genericbuild and the macro file that generates that file (EitherBuildMacro.hx).

I have the latest haxe nightly running. I copied some code of a library that uses genericbuild and runs on my computer. This I will call "reference code" from now on. But when I run the copied and modified above 3 files, I get the error messages:

> 1) 'Invalid number of type parameters for shl.ds.Either'
>
> 2) 'Enum> has no field _1'

It appears the macro can not be executed, also due to errors. It seems the library code which I took as an example doesnt run as an initialization macro, but as a build macro. This is probably the part where I am getting things wrong.

There are also errors about the macrofile (EitherBuildMacro.hx)

> 1) 'Class has no field defineType'
>
> 2) 'Class has no field currentPos'

When I look to the reference code, there all these fields do exist.

Main.hx

```
   class Main{
    public static function main(){
        var a:Either<String,Int>=Either._1('test'); //<--------
        var b:Either<String,Int>=Either._2(123);    //<--------
        }
    }
```

Either.hx

```
    package shl.ds;
    @:genericBuild(shl.macros.build.EitherBuildMacro.build()) //<--------
    enum Either<Rest> {} //<--------
```

EitherBuildMacro.hx

```
    import haxe.macro.Context;
    import haxe.macro.Expr;
    import haxe.macro.Type;

    using haxe.macro.Tools;

    class EitherBuildMacro {
    public static function build() {
        for (i in 2...11) {
            Context.defineType({            //<--------
                pack: [],
                name: "Either" + i,
                pos: Context.currentPos(),  //<--------
                kind: TDEnum,
                fields: [
                    for (j in 0...i) {
                        name: "_" + (j + 1),
                        kind: FFun({
                            args: [
                                {
                                    name: "value",
                                    type: TPath({
                                        name: String.fromCharCode(65 + j),
                                        pack: []
                                    })
                                }
                            ],
                            ret: null,
                            expr: null
                        }),
                        pos: Context.currentPos()
                    }
                ],
                params: [
                    for (j in 0...i) {
                        name: String.fromCharCode(65 + j)
                    }
                ]
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The reference code you can find here (https://gist.github.com/nadako/b086569b9fffb759a1b5)
This is the code I took as inspiration

Signal.hx

```
    @:genericBuild(SignalMacro.build())
    class Signal<Rest> {} //<--------
```

SignalMacro.hx

```
    import haxe.macro.Context;
    import haxe.macro.Expr;
    import haxe.macro.Type;

    using haxe.macro.Tools;

    class SignalMacro {
        static var signalTypes = new Map<Int,Bool>();

        static function build():ComplexType {
            return switch (Context.getLocalType()) {
                case TInst(_.get() => {name: "Signal"}, params):
                    buildSignalClass(params);
                default:
                    throw false;
            }
        }

        static function buildSignalClass(params:Array<Type>):ComplexType {
            var numParams = params.length;
            var name = 'Signal$numParams';

            if (!signalTypes.exists(numParams))
            {
                var typeParams:Array<TypeParamDecl> = [];
                var superClassFunctionArgs:Array<ComplexType> = [];
                var dispatchArgs:Array<FunctionArg> = [];
                var listenerCallParams:Array<Expr> = [];
                for (i in 0...numParams) {
                    typeParams.push({name: 'T$i'});
                    superClassFunctionArgs.push(TPath({name: 'T$i', pack: []}));
                    dispatchArgs.push({name: 'arg$i', type: TPath({name: 'T$i', pack: []})});
                    listenerCallParams.push(macro $i{'arg$i'});
                }

                var pos = Context.currentPos(); //<--------
                Context.defineType({ //<--------
                    pack: [],
                    name: name,
                    pos: pos,
                    params: typeParams,
                    kind: TDClass({
                        pack: [],
                        name: "Signal",
                        sub: "SignalBase",
                        params: [TPType(TFunction(superClassFunctionArgs, macro : Void))]
                    }),
                    fields: [
                        {
                            name: "dispatch",
                            access: [APublic],
                            pos: pos,
                            kind: FFun({
                                args: dispatchArgs,
                                ret: macro : Void,
                                expr: macro {
                                    startDispatch();
                                    var conn = head;
                                    while (conn != null) {
                                        conn.listener($a{listenerCallParams});
                                        if (conn.once)
                                            conn.dispose();
                                        conn = conn.next;
                                    }
                                    endDispatch();
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    ]
                });
                signalTypes[numParams] = true;
            }

            return TPath({pack: [], name: name, params: [for (t in params) TPType(t.toComplexType())]});
        }
    }
```

And some test driver code
Main.hx

```
    class Main {
        static function main() {
            var signal = new Signal<Int,String>(); //<--------
            var conn = signal.connect(function(a, b) {
                trace('Well done $a $b');
            });
            signal.dispatch(10, "lol");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think a `@:genericBuild` macro has to return a `ComplexType` (which the signal macro does, but your `Either` macro returns nothing). Also, the build function will be invoked multiple times for different type parameter combinations, so you shouldn't define types in a loop like that, but only build the one currently needed, and cache them in a map like the signal macro does.